# Initialize a python list with unique sets

Tags: python, list, initialization, set

I just realized that these two behave differently

```py
a = [set()] * 3

b = [set(), set(), set()]
```

a's elements will be the same instance of the set, i.e.

`a[0] is a[1] is a[2]` is true

b's elements will all be different instances of the set.

`b[0] is b[1] is b[2]` is false

I am wondering if there exists a technique to initialize a list with unique instances of sets in a smart way.

Or is this the only way:

```py
a = []
for i in range(3):
    a.append(set())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
b = [set() for i in range(3)]
```

Since the expression `set()` is evaluated for each iteration in the list comprehension, you get 3 distinct sets.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehensions.

```
a = [set() for i in range(3)]
```